# Scrolling to the top JPanel inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel, jscrollpane

I know a lot of people asked this question, but i still can't resolve this problem.
I have a JPanel inside a JScrollPane. JPanel contains six panels that are loaded dynamically.
After the panels are loaded the system makes a vertical autoscroll to the middle of the panel.
I have to avoid this, so I tried with this:

```
panel.scrollRectToVisible(scrollPane.getBounds());
```

But it doesn't work. 
My scrollPane has been created in this way

```
JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(panel.getBounds());
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: panel.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0,0,1,1)); ?

Comment: *"I know a lot of people asked this question,"*  I know a lot of people who have done no research start their message with that, to imply they have.  What are the top 3 SO threads you saw on the topic, and why did they not answer the question that has been asked many times before?

Comment: being rude will help you just as little as being lazy ;-) -1 for both attitudes.

Comment: unrelated: don't do manual sizing/locating (aka: call setBounds(...) ) of components, ever - that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `panel.scrollRectToVisible(scrollPane.getBounds());` should be `panel.scrollRectToVisible(JPanelAddedOnRuntime.getBounds());`
2. rest of code (posted here) coudn't be works,
3. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), short, runnable, compilable

EDIT

works, again you would need to re_read my above 3rd. point

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ScrollTesting {

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    private Vector<JTextField> fieldsVector = new Vector<JTextField>();
    private Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400, 40);
    private Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 1, 28);

    public ScrollTesting() {
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(100, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            fieldsVector.addElement(new JTextField());
            fieldsVector.lastElement().setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
            fieldsVector.lastElement().setFont(font);
            panel.add(fieldsVector.lastElement());
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTextField tf = (JTextField) fieldsVector.lastElement();
                panel.scrollRectToVisible(tf.getBounds());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScrollTesting scrollTesting = new ScrollTesting();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was that i didn't put the code panel.scrollRectToVisible(pan0.getBounds()); inside the SwingUtilities.invokeLater method.